# Find Infopath Template on server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath

Where can I find InfoPathTemplate on a server? Can I find it in the 14 hive?

I changed a domain address, and now my form from Infopath doesn't work. I must only change a domain, and this is an old template.

I don't have it saved on Infopath, only on Server.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using SharePoint 2007 use: [Get a working copy of your form template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/modify-a-published-form-template-HP010103091.aspx#BM2). 
   In short: Go to Advance Settings of your Library Settings; in the 'Document Template' section, click 'Edit Template'; using 'Save As', save the template to a folder on your computer.
2. If you are using SharePoint 2010, there is a slight change on the above method as follows: Every InfoPath form creates a Content Type with the name same as the name of your form. In the Library Settings page, under Content Type section, click on the content type link of your form [suppose the form was created with the name myForm, the content type link would have name myForm]. The rest of the procedure is the same as described in item 1 above.

Comment: Please add a brief description of the steps outlined in the link you reference. If the link breaks in the future, your answer will no longer be helpful.